# Problem in gradient operator and Kronecker delta function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, gradient-flows

I have this expression

$$\nabla_{i}\nabla_{j}\Big(\frac{1}{r}\Big)$$ Where $r$ is a distance. I tried this, but encountering manipulations of $\delta_{ij}$ with $\hat{r_i},\hat{r_{j}}$ and still stuck in here. The answer has this form:$$-\frac{(\delta_{ij}-3\hat{r_i}\hat{r_{j}})}{r^3}$$

Comment: If you know that $\nabla(r)=x/r$, then you should be able to deal with this using the chain rule, without having to get into individual indices. For instance, $\nabla(1/r)=-1/r^2 \nabla(r)=-x/r^3$.

Comment: $\nabla(r)=x/r$ comes because $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i}$ gives $\frac{1}{2 r}$ from the power, and then gives $2 x_i$ from the chain rule. The $2$'s cancel and you're left with $x_i/r$, so $\nabla(r)=x/r$. Now to apply $\nabla$ again, you do more or less the same thing, except you also need to figure out what $\nabla(x)$ (which is a matrix) is.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, but how does that lead to Kronecker delta function and unit vectors.I am having trouble with that too

Comment: The Kronecker delta part will come from $\nabla(x)$, which is actually the identity matrix. $\nabla(y)$ (when $y$ is a vector) is a matrix with $(\nabla(y))_{ij} = \frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}$. When $y=\nabla z$, $\nabla(y)$ is the Hessian matrix of $z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\nabla(\nabla(1/r)) & = \nabla(-(1/r^3) x) \\
(\nabla(\nabla(1/r)))_{ij} & = -\frac{\partial (x_i/r^3)}{\partial x_j} \\
& = -\frac{\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j} r^3 - \frac{\partial r^3}{\partial x_j} x_i}{r^6} \\
& = -\frac{\delta_{ij}}{r^3} + \frac{\frac{\partial r^3}{\partial x_j} x_i}{r^6} \\
& = -\frac{\delta_{ij}}{r^3} + \frac{3r^2 \frac{\partial r}{\partial x_j} x_i}{r^6}
\end{align*}

I think you can finish from here (since we already calculated $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_j}$ elsewhere).

Comment: @MaxQuantum $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_j} = \frac{x_j}{r}$ which I think is what you mean by $\hat{x_j}$. (It would be equal to $\hat{x}_j$, that is, the $j$th component of the unit vector, so that would make sense.) You remove the extra factor of $r$ in the denominator by writing $x_i=r \hat{x_i}$.

Comment: Thanks alot I got the answer :D.You are a very good supporter.